# Create multiple diffs from 100 files

Tags: git

I have a phabricator diff with changes on 100 files. I want to separate the diff into 3 diffs each with 20 files. How can I do that using arc and GIT?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? You will get better help here if you show particular approach and ask questions about something you're trying but is not working.

Comment: Which 40 files do you want to omit from the diffs?